# Why do external links open in the same tab?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined

I don't understand why when I put a link on an answer that the link opens up in the same tab for the end user.  There is hardly ever an instance where an end user wouldn't still be reading this site when wanting to see what is on the link.  I think the links should automatically open in a new tab - target="_blank".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window and its duplicates

Comment: This isn't really a DIY specific meta question, but a general SE one, and it's already been discussed there.

Comment: It seems clear its a semi-religious issue.  The workaround is to right-click open the link and select "new tab"